# Fee-free ATMs in Singapore?

Tags: singapore, fees-and-charges, atms

I have a US Capital One 360 Checking Account with a debit card (Mastercard). Capital One charges no fees for withdrawals, even internationally (outside the US).

It used to be (maybe 5 years ago) that I could use this card to withdraw from most Singapore ATMs without paying any additional fees.

However, recently I tried using this card again at two Singapore ATMs and both banks (DBS and I think OCBC) wanted to charge me a S$5 fee.

Where can I find a fee-free ATM for my card?

---

Edit: Yes my Capital One Debit Card **CHARGES NO FEES** for ATM withdrawals. I have tried at many ATMS in both the US and around the world.

Edit2: This question is not about whether my Capital One card or Mastercard charges any fees. Instead, it's about where in Singapore I can find an ATM that doesn't charge fees (e.g. the S$5 fee mentioned above charged by DBS and OCBC). If you don't actually know anything about ATMs in Singapore, please don't bother answering or commenting.

Comment: Are you sure they charge no fee, as opposed to reimbursing the fees others charge?  Capital doesn't own those ATMs, so they cannot prevent the owners from charging a fee.  But it's possible they might promise to reimburse fees.  My bank, Schwab, does that, and there are others that do it.

Comment: Contrarily, at least in the UK, there are fees charged by the ATM operator, and fees charged by your bank (the bank where the account is), and either or both may apply. So just because your bank isn't charging fees doesn't mean that you don't have to pay fees to the ATM operator (which may be another bank or a specialist ATM company). But maybe someone can find a free ATM for you.

Comment: Have you asked Capital One — the issuer of your bank card — for assistance in finding an ATM?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: No it is a nightmare contacting them for help with anything. They only have phone (no email or online form) and it takes at least 30 minutes before you connect to a real human being who will then take at least another hour to find an answer to any non-standard question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybank ATMs seem to charge no fees.

---

On 2022-05-08, I withdrew S$10 from a Maybank ATM* and was charged US$7.23 by my CapitalOne bank account.

According to XE the mid-market rate when I made the withdrawal was US$1 = S$1.3854048. So, at this rate, I should have paid S$10/1.3854048 ≈ US$7.2181. Hence, I paid about 0.16% over the mid-market rate. So yea I'd say I wasn't charged any fees.

*At [Grantral Mall](https://www.google.com/maps/place/(1.314319,%20103.765158)) (next to Clementi Mall)

Answer (score 3):

Hereby confirming that UOB doesn't charge any fees to overseas cardholders.  I stumbled across this thread after an OCBC ATM on North Bridge Street tried to charge a ridiculous $8 "access fee."  I went across the street to the bank of ATMs in the basement of Bugis Junction by the Cold Storage and UOB didn't charge a fee.  They did try to play the usual "dynamic conversion" game by offering to debit the withdrawal in USD at their own crappy rate, but that offer is easily declined.

Answer (score 0):

UOB ATMs do not charge any withdrawal fee for overseas ATM cards.

Comment: The system has flagged this as low quality because of its length/ Can you edit to give more details as the other answer has done?